# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'arr' was corrupted

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

int gcd(int value1, int value2)
{
    while (value1 != 0 && value2 != 0) 
    {
        if (value1 > value2)
            value1 = value1 - value2;
        else
            value2 = value2 - value1;
    }
    return value1 + value2;
}

void input_arr(int arr[], const int size) 
{
    srand(time(nullptr));
    //int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++) 
    {
        //std::cout << "Input array, index " << i << ": ";
        //std::cin >> temp;
        //if (temp > 0) 
            //arr[i] = temp;
        //else 
        //{
        //  std::cout << "Input value <= 0.";
        //  i--;
        //}
        arr[i] = rand();
    }
}

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        const int size = 27;
        int arr[size];
        input_arr(arr, size);
        int nod = 0; 
        int min = gcd(arr[0], arr[1]);
        int value1 = 0, value2 = 0, index1 = 0, index2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
        {
            if (i != size)
                nod = gcd(arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
            if (nod < min)
            {
                min = nod;
                index1 = i;
                index2 = i + 1;
                value1 = arr[i];
                value2 = arr[i + 1];
            }
        }
        if (index1 != 0 && index2 != 0)
        {
            std::cout << "GCD(" << value1 << ", " << value2 << ")" << " = " << min;
            std::cout << " Index = " << index1 << ", " << index2 << std::endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            std::cout << "GCD does not exist.";
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

За массив вроде не вылезаю, а всё равно есть проблема.

Comment: *"За массив вроде не вылезаю"* - а то

Comment: @user7860670, так может тогда скажете в чём проблема?)

Comment: Проблема в вылезании за границы массива...

Comment: @user7860670, где конкретнее ошибка?

Comment: Проще сказать где ее нет - `int min = gcd(arr[0], arr[1]);`, во всех остальных - вылезает.

Comment: @user7860670, я прошу показать не то место, где её нет, а то, где она действительно есть.

Comment: Я же написал - во всех обращениях к массиву, кроме `int min = gcd(arr[0], arr[1]);`

Answer (score 1):

В массивах индексация от [ 0 .. size-1 ]. А вы портите память arr [ size ].

Цикл в input_arr нужно уменьшить до :

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

а в main ещё меньше :

```
for (int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
```

Comment: не поверите, но я так делал. И всё равно ошибка есть)

Comment: @vanyavanya Вы бы лучше начали проверять индекс массива на валидность перед обращением по этому индексу...

Comment: @AlexGlebe, всё получилось, спасибо. Только почему так? Я же вроде всё правильно задавал, массив 27 элементов. Зачем мне уменьшать массив?

Comment: @AlexGlebe, получается, что в массиве 25 элементов, а не 27. Мне нужно все 27 элементов, для которых я и выделил память.

Comment: Допустим `size = 5` , тогда массив из пяти элементов имеет индексы 0 1 2 3 4. А в main вы ещё единичку добавляете. arr [ 3 + 1 ] = arr [ 4 ]